# SpringBoot JPA TransactionRequiredException when saveAndFlush is called

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I'm writing a SpringBoot REST server. I have some problems with the data access layer. In my saveReport() service method, if I call save() method of JPA repository, I can't see any records in the db. If I use saveAndFlush() method of JPA repository, I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
```

Db config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
  entityManagerFactoryRef = "qaEntityManagerFactory",
  basePackages = { "qa.repository" }
)
public class QADbConfig {

  @Bean(name = "qaDataSource")
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.qa-datasource")
  public HikariDataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
  }

  @Bean(name = "qaEntityManagerFactory")
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean 
  entityManagerFactory(
    EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
    @Qualifier("qaDataSource") DataSource dataSource
  ) {
    return builder
      .dataSource(dataSource)
      .packages("qa.model")
      .persistenceUnit("qa")
      .build();
  }

  @Bean(name = "qaTransactionManager")
  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
    @Qualifier("qaEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory 
    entityManagerFactory
  ) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
  }
}
```

In my service layer, I added @Transactional

```
@Service
public class ReportService implements IReportService {
  static final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

  @Autowired
  ReportRepository reportJpaRepository;

  @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
  @Override
  public Report saveReport(Report report) {
    reportJpaRepository.save(report); // I get no transaction exception if I use saveAndFlush method here
    return report;
  }
```

Also in the repository class, I added @Transactional

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public interface ReportJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<Report, Integer> {
  List<Report> findByPrivateReport(Boolean privateReport);
}
```

Do you see what is wrong with my code?

Thanks

Comment: The `@Transactional`  must define the tx manager it needs to use. Apparently you have multiple.

Comment: M.Deinum, which class should have the @Transactional, the service or repository?

Comment: The service in general. You can remove the annotations from your repository interface. You don't need them.